# How to concatinate two arrays of Struct in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to concatinate two arrays of struct in my query and keep getting a signature error.  The two Structs are identical (the fields in the struct match in type and number).

```
select order_id, case when h.filled is not null and rf.new is not null then array_concat( h.filled, rf.new)  else null end filled_and_new  from....
```

and it gives the error:

```
Error: No matching signature for function ARRAY_CONCAT for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<r_id STRING, s_id STRING, b_id STRING, ...>>, ARRAY<STRUCT<r_id STRING, s_id STRING, b_id STRING, ...>>. Supported signature: ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY, [ARRAY, ...]) at [10:18]
```

Does it mean that array_concat can not combine two arrays of Structs (with the same exact layout)?

Thanks

Here are the definitions of the two arrays:

```
reservations_filled RECORD  REPEATED    
reservations_filled.reservation_id  STRING  NULLABLE    
reservations_filled.s1_order_id STRING  NULLABLE    
reservations_filled.s2_order_id STRING  NULLABLE    
reservations_filled.amount  INTEGER NULLABLE    
reservations_filled.created_time    TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
reservations_filled.updated_time    TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
reservations_filled.state   STRING  NULLABLE    
reservations_filled.rate    FLOAT   NULLABLE    
reservations_filled.u_amount    INTEGER NULLABLE    
reservations_filled.u_fees  INTEGER NULLABLE
```

and the array in the joined table:

```
rsrvtn_array    RECORD  REPEATED    
rsrvtn_array.reservation_id STRING  NULLABLE    
rsrvtn_array.s1_order_id    STRING  NULLABLE    
rsrvtn_array.s2_order_id    STRING  NULLABLE    
rsrvtn_array.amount INTEGER NULLABLE    
rsrvtn_array.created    TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
rsrvtn_array.updated    TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
rsrvtn_array.state  STRING  NULLABLE    
rsrvtn_array.rate   FLOAT   NULLABLE    
rsrvtn_array.u_amount   INTEGER NULLABLE    
rsrvtn_array.u_fees INTEGER NULLABLE
```

and the query is:

```
 select t1.rsrvtn_array a, t2.reservations_filled b , array_concat(t1.rsrvtn_array, t2.reservations_filled) c from temp.new_orders t1 join temp.order_history t2 on using(order_id)
```

Comment: Take a look at the table's schema in the UI, since the fields in the STRUCTs must be different. The error message truncates the type names to avoid being too verbose. It would be helpful to include the fields of both STRUCTs in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean that array_concat can not combine two arrays of Structs (with the same exact layout)?

ARRAY_CONCAT will combine two arrays of STRUCTs with the same exact schema!
See example/prove below

```sql
#standardSQL
with data AS (
SELECT  
  ARRAY<STRUCT<r_id STRING, s_id STRING, b_id STRING>>[('r1', 's1', 'b1')] AS x1,
  ARRAY<STRUCT<r_id STRING, s_id STRING, b_id STRING>>[('r2', 's2', 'b2'), ('r3', 's3', 'b3')] AS x2
UNION ALL
SELECT  
  ARRAY<STRUCT<r_id STRING, s_id STRING, b_id STRING>>[('r5', 's5', 'b5')] AS x1,
  NULL AS x2
)  
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT(x1, x2) AS y
FROM data
```

So, most likely the schema in your two arrays are actually different - in this case error message will be as you see it - see example below for such scenario

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, ARRAY<STRUCT<r_id STRING, s_id STRING, b_id STRING, c_id STRING>>
    [('r1', 's1', 'b1', 'c1')] AS x1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, ARRAY<STRUCT<r_id STRING, s_id STRING, b_id STRING, c_id STRING>>
    [('r5', 's5', 'b5', 'c5')] AS x1
),  
data2 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, ARRAY<STRUCT<r_id STRING, s_id STRING, b_id STRING, cc_id STRING>>
    [('r2', 's2', 'b2', 'c2'), ('r3', 's3', 'b3', 'c3')] AS x2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, NULL AS x2
)  
SELECT data1.id,  ARRAY_CONCAT(data1.x1, data2.x2) AS y
FROM data1 
JOIN data2 
ON data1.id = data2.id
```

the error here is exactly as you see in your example

```sql
Error: NO matching signature FOR FUNCTION ARRAY_CONCAT FOR argument types: 
ARRAY<STRUCT<r_id STRING, s_id STRING, b_id STRING, ...>>,
ARRAY<STRUCT<r_id STRING, s_id STRING, b_id STRING, ...>>. 
Supported signature: ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY, [ARRAY, ...]) AT  [15:23]
```

Error message gets cut so those visible fields are sure same, but in reality - the last fields - c and cc - (that is cut off) are different in both arrays

Hope this helps!

> Update

Check out below fragments from both achemas:

```sql
reservations_filled.created_time    TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
reservations_filled.updated_time    TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
```

and

```sql
rsrvtn_array.created    TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
rsrvtn_array.updated    TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
```

Clearly exactly the case I predicted in my above examples

> Solution

so, below will fail as expected

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 1 AS id,  
  ARRAY<STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING, cc STRING>>[('a1', 'b1', 'c1')] AS x
),
t2 AS (
SELECT 1 AS id,  
  ARRAY<STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING, c STRING>>[('a2', 'b2', 'c2')] AS y
)
SELECT x, y, ARRAY_CONCAT(x, y) AS z
FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING(id)
```

because (a,b,c) and (a,b,cc) have one element with different name

And, below will work

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 1 AS id,  
  ARRAY<STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING, cc STRING>>[('a1', 'b1', 'c1')] AS x
),
t2 AS (
SELECT 1 AS id,  
  ARRAY<STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING, c STRING>>[('a2', 'b2', 'c2')] AS y
)
SELECT x, y, 
  ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT a, b, cc AS c FROM UNNEST(x)), y) AS z
FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING(id)
```

because cc was "dynamically" aliased to c thus making schamas not just similar by layout but identical

Hope now it helps

In case you will have problem in applying above solution to your example  - see below :o)

```sql
SELECT
  t1.rsrvtn_array a,
  t2.reservations_filled b,
  ARRAY_CONCAT(
    ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT 
        reservation_id, 
        s1_order_id, 
        s2_order_id, 
        amount, created AS created_time, 
        updated AS updated_time, 
        state, 
        rate, 
        u_amount, 
        u_fees 
      FROM UNNEST(t1.rsrvtn_array)
    ) , t2.reservations_filled) AS c
FROM temp.new_orders t1
JOIN temp.order_history t2
ON USING(order_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried an example and worked too.  However, I still have trouble with my original query, even though the signature is the same.  Here are the two array definitions:

Comment: did you mean to provide arrays definitions in your comment? please provide whole query and more details  - otherwise no way to help you

Comment: I just added the query to the main post as well.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: see solution added to answer

Comment: Thank you. I had misunderstood the signature to be the field types (matching by field types).  I didn't know that it tries matching by field name.  Thanks for the explanation.  It works now.

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help you